# Expected Value formula definition

Tags: probability, measure-theory

When defining the expected value:

$$ \mu = E(X) = \int_{\Omega} X \, dP = \int_{\mathbb{R}} x \, dP_X = \int_{\mathbb{R}} x \, dF $$

I don't understand how is $\displaystyle \int_{\mathbb{R}}x \, dF$ defined if $F$ is not a measure.

Comment: Like so: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integral

Comment: Thank you! I was thinking in terms of Lebesgue integration. In fact I didn't know this type of integration existed.

Comment: Stieltjes integral could be Riemann or Lebesgue.

Comment: There is Lebesgue- Stieltjes integral, too.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integration